# Como agregar el valor que viene del modelo al textbox

Tags: .net, devexpress, mvc, grid, edittext

Buenas quisiera saber como agregar el valor que viene del modelo a un `textbox` que esta en la fila de una tabla, en Devexpress este es el código que tengo me falta una linea de código si no estoy mal es algo así `content.Column` pero no recuerdo el resto y no lo encuentro agradezco cualquier ayuda gracias.

```
 settings.Columns.Add(c =>
        {
            c.FieldName = "Unidades";
            c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
            c.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            c.SetDataItemTemplateContent(content =>
            {
                Html.DevExpress().TextBox(set =>
                {
                    set.Name = "TxtUnid" + content.VisibleIndex;
                    set.Text = content.Column;
                    set.Width = 40;
                }).Render();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Si analizamos la respuesta del foro oficial de `Devexpress`

[GridView - How to set a TextBox value in the Column's DataItemTemplate based on the value of another TextBox](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q457806)

veras que alli menciona utilizar el `DataBinder.Eval()`

```
col.SetDataItemTemplateContent(diTemplate => {
        GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer container = diTemplate as GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer;
        Html.DevExpress().TextBox(txtSettings => {
            txtSettings.Name = string.Format("txt_{0}", diTemplate.VisibleIndex);
            txtSettings.Text = DataBinder.Eval(diTemplate.DataItem, diTemplate.Column.FieldName).ToString();
            txtSettings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.GotFocus = string.Format("function(s, e) {{OnValueGotFocus(s, e, '{0}', '{1}'); }}", container.KeyValue.ToString(), container.Column.FieldName);
        }).Render();
    });
```